# Unknown Litium Ion Batterys

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, laptop

i have a laptop battery pack which i took apart and kept the batteries, hoping to make a battery bank, but the problem is i cant find any info on the batteries, they are all red and have a green mark on top indicating positive and there's some writing, so I've went into looking them up but nothing comes up, so i need help in figuring out what kind of battery is it. a 14500 or a 18650 cell, all i know is that the battery pack is a Rechargeable li-ion battery with 11.1v and capacity of 53wh, battery's voltages are between 1.2v - 3.8v

---

65MM for Height And 18MM for Diameter = 18650 Cell

Comment: Measure the diameter and length and you know weather it's an 14500 or 18650.

Comment: 65MM for Height And 18MM for Diameter

Comment: 18+65=18650. metric math. anything <3V may be expired with  1k to 12V monitor the dv/dt rate closely and record in the 3 to 4V range for each cell every hour

Comment: thanks for that, now I'd love to know what are the battery's mAH and Max Voltage are, so is that possible to find out. And I have read online saying not to discharge a Li-Ion battery under 2.5v or something, so why is that ? and how do you know if the battery is dead or its still a good one

Comment: @Xios Please ask a specific question, it helps the readers. Check this out: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Please also use proper punctuation

Comment: 11.1V = 3 cells in series. 53Wh / 11.1 = 5(ish) Ah so presumably 2 cells in parallel, 6 cells in 3S2P. (You might have told us how many cells.) Making each cell about 2.5Ah, typical for an 18650. Consider any cells below 2.5V as un-recoverable and a serious fire risk when charging. Now, did you have a question?

Comment: There where 6 total cells.

Comment: @BrianDrummond There is a specific question there. It's just not put in the narrowly "correct" way that some minds (seem to) demand. While it is 'a good idea' [tm] to learn to accommodate the limitations of others in formulating their questions, that works both ways.

Comment: If you want questions to be treated well you **MUST** at a minimum make an attempt to format them well. You will find that this is vital if you do not do it. Sentences MUST start with capital letters. You should use proper sentences and not run on and on and on and on with commas between thoughts. | Some internet searching on battery types and dimensions would have easily shown you what 14500 and 1865- meant. Some basic battery tutorials will show you how to calculate cell mAh from the information you have. Showing people that you have done basic research gets you better answers.

Comment: @Xios - Sometimes you can see through the red poly-sleeve to see cell identification information. I suggest you look very carefully at each cell under bright task lighting. The max V of each li-ion cell depends on its chemistry. Different chemistries have different max charge voltages.  Some chemistries require the cells to not be discharged below 3V and others set the limit to 2.5V.  It is possible to monitor an unknown cell while it is discharging & watch/record (using software) to determine ...

Comment: exactly what V it fails to deliver it's rated power (the discharge cutoff V should be above that voltage level).  I don't recommend you do such a test as you are clearly a li-ion cell novice.  If you discharge below that V, it tends to destroy the cell.  You know if a cell is bad if it won't charge (open or shorted cell) or if it over-heats when charging (usually a shorted cell) or if it doesn't hold a charge (usually has micro-shorts) after it is removed from a charger or it reached the proper V when charging, but it won't deliver sufficient current to a load when put into service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Dimensions and type:**

Cylindrical cells with types like 14500 and 18650 use a naming system of
diameter in mm + length in mm + 0
So

- 14500 = 14 + 50 + 0 = 14mm dia, 50mm long
- 18650 = 18 + 65 + 0 = 18mm dia, 65mm long

Diameter dimensions are reasonably close - say +/- 0.5mm usually.
Length dimensions may be a few mm different.
Nipple ended and/or "Protected" 18650 cells tend to be a few mm longer than flat ended and/or unprotected cells.

**_________________________________**

**Cell & battery Voltage, mAh capacity, Wh capacity**

LiIon cells have usual operating ranges of 2.5V - 4.2V but discharge below 3V gives very little energy and risks cell damage.  Cells under 2.5V may be dead. Cells under 2.0V are probably dangerously dead. A cell in the 2.0 - 2.5V range may be test charged at VERY LOW current - say C/100 or perhaps <= C/10 to see if it charges up to > 2.5V. Charging a cell that is below 2.5V at full rate risks catastrophic failure. Charging a  cell that is below 2V at high rate is an act of lunacy.

Charge rates for good cells may be as high as C/1 but C/2 is safer.

Cells are considered to have nominal (or average) voltages of 3.6V or 3.7V when batteruy voltage is calculated. So your 11.1V nominal voltage indicates 3 cells in series (3S) as 11.1/3 = 3.7V per cell.

Cell Wh capacity = nominal voltage x Ah capacity.
Ah = Wh/V
53 Wh/3.7V = 14.32 Ah at 3.7V.  .
If there were 3 cells Ah/cell = 14.32/3 = 4.77 Ah/cell.
Too high.
If there are 6 cells then Ah/cell = 14.32/6 = 2.39 = 2.4 AH/cell.
This is about right for cells produced some years ago.

So the battery is arranged as 6 cells in 3S2P configuration with 2.4 Ah/ cell.

Max charge for good cells at C/2 = 2.4/2 = 1.2A max charge per cell.

**___________________________________**

**Suggested procedure:**

**Be aware that there is a potential for 'vent with flames' events or (less likely) possibly more dangerous self dismantlement.**

Separate cells into 3 groups

V >=3V
2.5V <= V < 3V
V < 2.5V

Cells < 2.5V are probably dead, but maybe not.

Use a charging source of > 3.9V and =< 4V.
NOT 4.1V. NOT 4.2V
Cells may be 'floated' semi-indefinitely at <= 4.0V.
Doing this at much above 4V risks permanent cell damage or catastrophic failure.

Low or very low V cells have a low "trickle up" charging current applied to see if they can be charged back into the normal range. Cells that have been below 2V are very likely badly damaged or dead. Force feeding a cell measuring < 2V may cause catastrophic failure.

Assume trickle up current of <= ~~ C/50 = 2400 mA/50 ~= 50 mA
For < 2.5V cells charge cells via series 47 to 100 Ohm resistor.
( R = V/I = 4V/0.050A = 80 Ohm)

For <= 2.5 cells charge from 4V via series 4.7 to 10 Ohm resistor.
(ie at say ~~= C/10. I = V/R = (4-2.5)/0.24 ~= 6 Ohms.)

If cells under 2.5V fail to rise to >=3V after 'some while' discard them in an appropriate manner.

If cells > 2.5V do not continue to charge towards 4V discard them.